# Magento 2 : Modal Popup using Ajax

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax, modal-popup

How to use model popup using ajax?
Can any one help for this.
Here below my code.
How can i apply in this code model popup?
And also post data get in popup. How it possible?

**app/code/Vendor/Complany/view/frontend/web/js/example.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,example,modal) {
        return {
            exampleData:function(ajaxurl){
                $("#example").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:ajaxurl,
                        type:'POST',
                        showLoader: true,
                        dataType:'json',          
                        success:function(){
                            alert('test');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**app/cpde/Vendor/Company/view/frontend/templates/example/example.phtml**

```
<div id="events_popup" style="display: none;" class="events_popup">

<script>
        require(
            ['jquery','Vendor_Company/js/example'],
            function($,example){
                var ajaxurl = '<?php echo //My URL using block function; ?>';
                example.exampleData(ajaxurl);
            }
        );
</script>
```

Comment: have you try with $("#events_popup") instead of $("#example")?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Here $("#example") is button id

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,example,modal) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: 'primary action submit btn btn-default',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };
        return {
            exampleData:function(ajaxurl){
                $("#example").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $form = $('#form-validate');
                    var data = $('#form-validate').serialize();
                    if(!$form.valid()) return false;
                        $.ajax({
                            url:ajaxurl,
                            type:'POST',
                            showLoader: true,
                            dataType:'json',
                            data: data,
                            complete: function(data) {
                                $('#email_address').val("");
                                $("#events_popup").html('Thanks.').modal(options).modal('openModal');
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                            }
                        });
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```